# Dart: How to convert a List<dynamic> to a List<Player>

Tags: dart

I am getting data from a server via a signalR hook and I need to shape it into a `List<Player>`

Here is the receiving function, and sample data

```
connection.on('ReceiveLatestList', (message) {
  //TODO: Convert server data into List<Player>
  try {
    List<Player> players = message as List<Player>;
  } catch (e) {
    print(e);
  }
});
```

The `message` data looks like this:
[image]

What's the best way to transform this into a `List<Player>`

Player class

```
import 'dart:core';
import 'dart:math';

class Player {
  int guestId;
  String name;
  int roomNumber;
  int vote;

  Player.create(this.name, this.roomNumber) {
    int min = 100000000;
    int max = 999999999;
    var random = new Random();
    this.guestId = min + random.nextInt(max - min);
    this.vote = 0;
  }

  String toJson(Player p) {
    return '{"guestId":"$guestId", "name":"$name","roomNumber":"$roomNumber","vote":"$vote"}';
  }
}
```

Comment: can you please post your json as code>

Answer (score 0):

Iterate `json items` of list and add them to List of type Player

```
List<Player> players= List<Player>.from(json.map((i) => Player.fromJson(i)));
```

and also add fromJson  method to Player's class:

```
 Player.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> map)
 { 
   this.someFeild= map['someFeild'];
   this.someOtherFeild= map['someOtherFeild'];
    ...
  }
```

Comment: it does not work. ```list[0]``` is the entire json string and there is no list[1], 2, 3.

https://i.imgur.com/JpiVSnZ.png

Comment: oh sorry. I misundrstood your question.I editted my answer